# backbone.js model attribute undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am fetching a collection of model objects from a rest url in backbone. I then iterate over the collection and use underscore template helper method to with data from model. But I am getting undefined defaultImg when call the attribute.

View:

```
 define (['jquery','underscore','backbone'],function($,_,Backbone){
PopVideoView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    tagName:"li",
    //template: _.template($('#popView').html()),
    template: _.template("<li><img src='<%= defaultImg %>'/></li>"),
    render: function ()
    {
        console.log(this.model.toJSON());
        this.template(this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.html(this.template);
        return this;
    }
});
return PopVideoView;
});
```

another view:

```
define(['jquery','underscore','backbone','collections/PopVideos','views/PopVideo'],function($,_,Backbone){
PopVideosView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    el:"#pop",
    render: function ()
    {
        this.collection.each (function(video)
        {
            popVideoView = new PopVideoView({model:video});
            this.$el.append (popVideoView.render().el).hide().fadeIn(300);
        },this);
        return this;
    },
});
return PopVideosView;
});
```

This is what I am getting from Chrome developer console:

```
Object {video_id: "1G4isv_Fylg", video_name: "Coldplay - Paradise ", defaultImg: "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/1G4isv_Fylg/mqdefault.jpg", genre: "pop", date: "Feb 16, 2013 1:01:33 PM"…}
Uncaught ReferenceError: defaultImg is not defined
```

what I am doing wrong?

This is the model & collection:

```
 define (['jquery','underscore','backbone'],function($,_,Backbone){
Video = Backbone.Model.extend ({
    urlRoot:"/video",
});
return Video;
});//end define

define(['backbone','models/Video'],function(Backbone,Video) {
PopVideosCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend ({
    model:Video,
    url:"/pop/3/1"
});
return PopVideosCollection;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem I just need to do this:

```
this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

instead of:

```
this.template(this.model.toJSON());
this.$el.html(this.template);
```

Comment: Right, if you hand `html()` a function, it will call that function but jQuery won't give your template function the arguments that it is expecting.

Answer (score 1):

The `render` method in your `PopVideoView` has some problems:

```
template: _.template("<li><img src='<%= defaultImg %>'/></li>"),
render: function ()
{
    console.log(this.model.toJSON());
    this.template(this.model.toJSON());
    this.$el.html(this.template);
    return this;
}
```

When you call [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template), you get a function back so this:

```
this.template(this.model.toJSON());
```

makes sense except that you're throwing away the HTML return value. This part:

```
this.$el.html(this.template);
```

is where you go wrong, you're passing a function to jQuery's `html` method and from the [fine manual](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2):

> .html( function(index, oldhtml) )
>
> **function(index, oldhtml)**
>
> A function returning the HTML content to set.

So jQuery is calling your `this.template` function with arguments that it doesn't understand. Then the compiled template function goes looking for `defaultImg` somewhere, doesn't find it, and you get a `ReferenceError` because there is no `defaultImg`.

You don't want to pass the function to `html()`, you want to *evaluate* the template function and hand its return value to `html()`:

```
render: function ()
{
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
}
```

And BTW, you really should be using `var` when defining your views and models:

```
define (['jquery','underscore','backbone'],function($,_,Backbone){
    var PopVideoView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    ^^^
```

Those variables are global if you don't `var` them.